# how to check if value in a DataFrame is a type Decimal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a data test for some api calls that return a DataFrame with a date type and a type Decimal. I can't find a way to verify the Decimal

the DataFrame is returned as 2022-01-18 12:35:00  2856.8430

So I have

```
result = ds.DataService.get_recent(5, 24)
assert not result.empty
assert ptypes.is_datetime64_any_dtype(result['foo'])
```

but if I try

```
assert all(ptypes.is_float_dtype(result[col]) for col in result["foo1"])

 raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: Decimal('2873.6408')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given a series like `result["foo1"]`, you can check that with

```py
from decimal import Decimal

import pandas as pd

is_decimal: bool = pd.core.dtypes.common.is_dtype_equal(result["foo1"], Decimal)
```

Comment: `se` being `result["foo1"]` for example.

Comment: Thanks, unsure why I could not find this on the web, succinct and clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the usage of `is_dtype_equal` function as suggested yields `True` if the Series is of another `object` types. What worked for me was using `isinstance(x, Decimal)` on of the the Series elements.

See example:

```
from decimal import Decimal

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': ['A','B','C'] ,
        'b': [11.1, 23.3,55.5],
        'c': [Decimal(10.0), Decimal(11.1), Decimal(12.1)]
    }
)
print("Using isinstance of")
print(isinstance(df['a'].values[0], Decimal))
print(isinstance(df['b'].values[0], Decimal))
print(isinstance(df['c'].values[0], Decimal))

print("Using is_dtype_equal")
print(pd.core.dtypes.common.is_dtype_equal(df['a'], Decimal))
print(pd.core.dtypes.common.is_dtype_equal(df['b'], Decimal))
print(pd.core.dtypes.common.is_dtype_equal(df['c'], Decimal))
```